# Highcharts dynamic name with coldfusion

Tags: highcharts, coldfusion

I am using Highcharts to display a pie chart. I am trying to output a coldfusion query that has two fields. A classification name and a count. I am struggling to have the name display. When I hard the name as something like 'Classification' it works and builds the chart based on the counts. If I add the #classification# variable to the name it does not display anything.

Here is what I am trying that produces no results.

```
series: [{
    name: 'Classification',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [
    <cfoutput query="qryCounts">
    {
        name: #classification#,
        y: #count#
    },
    </cfoutput>
  ]
}]
```

This is what works, but displays the same name for every classification.

```
series: [{
        name: 'Classification',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [
        <cfoutput query="qryCounts">
        {
            name: 'Classification',
            y: #count#
        },
        </cfoutput>
      ]
    }]
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to put quotes around the variable #classification#?

Comment: `y: #count#` works because y is numeric.  However, `name: #classification#` doesn't work because name is a string.  Therefore you need to output it with quotes like this `name: '#classification#'`

Comment: That also does not render anything. I had tried that before.

Comment: If a hard coded string works, there's no obvious reason the same code wouldn't work with dynamic values, unless the code is different or maybe the query values contain bad chars. A) post a dump of the query data b) look at the js console for errors

Comment: @spacerobot Do you have any apostrophes (single quotes) as values in the `classification` column?  If so, then that would definitely be the cause of an error.  If you do have apostrophes, then you can either escape them, or use double quotes as your string termination delimiter, provided that you don't have double quotes in your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always try using [encodeForJavascript()](https://cfdocs.org/encodeforjavascript) whenever you output a cfml variable as direct Javascript code.

That will ensure that:

- strings are properly escaped, so your Javascript won't break (e.g. when an apostrophe, backslashes
  , linebreaks or other special characters are inside your string)
- your application gets safer against XSS attacks

For detecting such Javascript erros created by non-escaped variables, look at your console output in your browsers web development tool (as already mentioned by one of the commenters). There you'll see the code and the string that is breaking the Javascript with an exception.

Also, if you are injecting Javascript into an html attribute, such as `'onClick'` you better also encode using `encodeForHTMLAttribute()` , for example:

```html
<cfsavecontent variable="alertText">
 "This text has linebreaks,
slashes like / or \ and apostrophes ' that
would break any javascript code on output" but also german umlaute lke ä or ö or ü
</cfsavecontent>
<cfoutput>

    <button onClick="alert('#encodeForHTMLAttribute( encodeForJavascript( alertText ) )#');">Working click me</button>

    <button onClick="alert('#alertText#');">Broken click me</button>

</cfoutput>
```